# Getting a close review in the low quality queue

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I was reviewing in the low quality queue and got this.

> [image]

as opposed to:

> [image]

Possibly an audit glitch?

Is this a bug?

Comment: Woah... That's a `#bug`. Or may be it is not closed?

Comment: @PraveenKumar wierd hey, I didn't know what to press I was like hm..

Comment: Ha ha. LoL... Let the team answer.

Comment: This can probably happen if people use the "question is very low quality" from the H&I queue, this casts a very low quality flag in their name.

Comment: Cross-meta dupe: [Why does LQP still have question audits?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289627/why-does-lqp-still-have-question-audits)

Comment: Note that this is only relevant to SO: all other sites fling questions into LQP with abandon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug.

As far as I know, only answers (which are most commonly flagged as VLQ) can be voted-to-delete from the LQ review queue. Questions have to get closed, and eventually they will be deleted. I think the close option is the right option here.

You are not getting an item from the Close Review queue as you think you get, but from the Low Quality queue, it is just not very common to get a question there.

Comment: hm. and no delete option. It doesn't make sense to put it there..

Comment: No, questions need to be closed before they can be deleted.

Comment: yeh, but you think they'd be closed first

Comment: This sounds right, on EE.SE I see quite a few questions in the VLQ queue, it's just someone flagging that way instead of using a close reason type flag, or very short questions seem to end up there automatically.

Comment: @Yvette This is the correct answer - the LQP queue is functioning as intended here. See hichris123's comment on the question above for a site-specific bug report regarding bad audit selection on Stack Overflow.